# Accessing the [] operator from a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, operators

If I define a pointer to an object that defines the `[]` operator, is there a direct way to access this operator from a pointer?

For example, in the following code I can directly access `Vec`'s member functions (such as `empty()`) by using the pointer's `->` operator, but if I want to access the `[]` operator I need to first get a reference to the object and then call the operator.

```
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> Vec(1,1);
    std::vector<int>* VecPtr = &Vec;

if(!VecPtr->empty())      // this is fine
    return (*VecPtr)[0]; // is there some sort of ->[] operator I could use?

return 0;
}
```

I might very well be wrong, but it looks like doing `(*VecPtr).empty()` is less efficient than doing `VecPtr->empty()`. Which is why I was looking for an alternative to `(*VecPtr)[]`.

Comment: **Why** do you want to avoid `(*VecPtr)[0]` ?

Comment: @Rob Edited with a reason. My assumption might be wrong, but it's why I asked.

Comment: `(*VecPtr).empty()` and `VecPtr->empty()` are exactly the same thing (unless VecPtr is something that overloads `operator*` and `operator->` with conflicting meaning.

Comment: If `VecPtr` is a pointer type, then `(*VecPtr).XXX` is, by definition, equivalent to `VecPtr->XXX`. There is no loss of efficiency. If `VecPtr` is a non-pointer type that implements `operator*` and `operator[]`, then you'll have to examine them to see which is more efficient (they are probably the same).

Comment: @KerrekSB because some people don't know how to get at the operator[] from a pointer _at all_.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You could do any of the following:

```
#include <vector>

int main () {
  std::vector<int> v(1,1);
  std::vector<int>* p = &v;

  p->operator[](0);
  (*p)[0];
  p[0][0];
}
```

By the way, in the particular case of `std::vector`, you might also choose: `p->at(0)`, even though it has a slightly different meaning.

Comment: That last one there is interesting, could you explain what is happening there under the hood? Is that first [0] referring to the "first element" pointed to by the pointer? Similar to how a vector reference is a pointer to the beginning to an array?

Comment: @ThekoLekena exactly, for pointers to complete-types T, the [] operator is defined to access the ith element of the array (by calculating sizeof(T) * i). Of course, since in this case we have a pointer to **one** vector, having anything else than [0] would be undefined behaviour.

**edit**: i wouldn't choose the last one though, as i find it less idiomatic.

Comment: @ancientchild agreed, the last one should not be used as normal practice.

Answer (score 12):

```
return VecPtr->operator[](0);
```

...will do the trick.  But really, the `(*VecPtr)[0]` form looks nicer, doesn't it?

Answer (score 4):

`(*VecPtr)[0]` is perfectly OK, but you can use the `at` function if you want:

```
VecPtr->at(0);
```

Keep in mind that this (unlike `operator[]`) will throw an `std::out_of_range` exception if the index is not in range.

Answer (score 4):

There's another way, you can use a reference to the object:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v = {7};
    vector<int> *p = &v;

    // Reference to the vector
    vector<int> &r = *p;
    cout << (*p)[0] << '\n'; // Prints 7
    cout <<    r[0] << '\n'; // Prints 7

    return 0;
}
```

This way, `r` is the same as `v` and you can substitute all occurrences of `(*p)` by `r`.

**Caveat:** This will only work if you **won't modify the pointer** (i.e. change which object it points to).

Consider the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v = {7};
    vector<int> *p = &v;

    // Reference to the vector
    vector<int> &r = *p;
    cout << (*p)[0] << '\n'; // Prints 7
    cout <<    r[0] << '\n'; // Prints 7

    // Caveat: When you change p, r is still the old *p (i.e. v)
    vector<int> u = {3};
    p = &u; // Doesn't change who r references
    //r = u; // Wrong, see below why
    cout << (*p)[0] << '\n'; // Prints 3
    cout <<    r[0] << '\n'; // Prints 7

    return 0;
}
```

`r = u;` is wrong because you can't change references:
This will *modify the vector referenced by `r`* (`v`)
instead of referencing another vector (`u`).
So, again, this only works if the pointer won't change while still using the reference.

*The examples need C++11 only because of `vector<int> ... = {...};`*

Comment: `r = u;` is fine and it will do assignment between the two vectors ; this has nothing to do with `p`

Comment: And this is what I mean by "wrong". Quoting myself, "you can substitute all occurrences of `(*p)` by `r`", but "This will only work if you won't modify the pointer", because there's no way to change `r` as you would change the value of `*p`. `r = u;` "will modify the vector referenced by `r` instead of referencing another vector" -- it won't have the intended effect.

Comment: `r = u;` will have the same effect whether or not you later modify the pointer

Comment: Yes, but I don't get why you're saying that. Again, by "wrong" I mean it doesn't do what `p = ...` would do. And I'm talking about substituting all ocurrences of `*p` by `r`. But if in your code you have `p = ...`, replacing `p = ...` by `r = ...` is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You can use it as `VecPrt->operator [] ( 0 )`, but I'm not sure you'll find it less obscure.

Answer (score 1):

It is worth noting that in C++11 std::vector has a member function 'data' that returns a pointer to the underlying array (both const and non-const versions), allowing you to write the following:

```
VecPtr->data()[0];
```

This might be an alternative to

```
VecPtr->at(0);
```

which incurs a small runtime overhead, but more importantly it's use implies you aren't checking the index for validity before calling it, which is not true in your particular example.

See [std::vector::data](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) for more details.

Answer (score -3):

People are advising you to use `->at(0)` because of range checking. But here is my advise (with other point of view):

**NEVER** use `->at(0)`! It is really slower. Would you sacrifice performance just because you are lazy enough to not check range by yourself? If so, you should not be programming in C++.

I think `(*VecPtr)[0]` is ok.

Comment: why at(0) is slow?