# Calling overloaded operator () from object pointer

Tags: c++

Consider the following:

```
class MyClass {
public:
   int operator ()(int a, int b);
};
```

When having:

```
MyClass* m = new MyClass();
```

I want to access the `operator()` method, so I could:

```
(*m)(1,2);
```

But can I do this?

```
m->(1,2);
```

Comment: `mydummy` one second, `T` the next?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Not with that syntax, but you can do

```
 m->operator()(1,2);
```

Comment: But note that if you find yourself needing to do this a lot, it may be easier and more readable to just define a normal member function.  e.g. `m->do_it(1,2);`

Comment: Yeah I hate this syntax. @DavidC. you might not this option when working with 3rd party code. I prefer the syntax (*m)(1,3) -- either way it is ugly.

Answer (score 8):

If you won't change `m` (what it points to), you can substitute `(*m)` by a reference:

```
MyClass *m = new MyClass();
MyClass &r = *m;
r(1, 2);
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46328727/3341238) for more details.